# Python: Trying to restart script not working

Tags: python, exec, restart

Tried to restart my python script within itself.
Python 2.7.11

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import os
import sys
os.execv(__file__, sys.argv)
sys.exit()
```

Result:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "...\foo.py", line 3, in <module>
        os.execv(__file__, sys.argv)
OSError: [Errno 8] Exec format error
```

Another code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import os
import sys
os.execv(sys.executable, [sys.executable] + sys.argv)
sys.exit()
```

Result:

```
C:\...\python.exe: can't open file 'C:\...\Math': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

The file's name is foo.py - it's in a folder name 'Math Project'

Codepage: 852, if necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error message `C:\...\python.exe` suggests that you're running a Windows system.

Your first script fails because under Windows, `os.execv()` doesn't know how to handle Python scripts because the first line (`#!/usr/bin/python`) is not evaluated nor does it point to a valid Python interpreter on most Windows systems. In effect, `os.execv()` tries to execute a plain text file which happens to contain Python code, but the system doesn't know that.

Your second script fails to correctly retrieve the file name of your Python script `foo.py`. It's not clear to me why that happens, but the error message suggests that there might be a problem with the space in your directory name `Math Project`.

As a possible workaround, try replacing the line

```py
os.execv(sys.executable, [sys.executable] + sys.argv)
```

by the following:

```py
os.execv(sys.executable, 
         [sys.executable, os.path.join(sys.path[0], __file__)] + sys.argv[1:])
```

This line attempts to reconstruct the correct path to your Python script, and pass it as an argument to the Python interpreter.

As a side note: Keep in mind what your script is doing: it's unconditionally  starting another instance of itself. This will result in an infinite loop, which will eventually bring down your system. Make sure that your real script contains an abort condition.

**EDIT:**

The problem lies, indeed, with the space in the path, and the workaround that I mentioned won't help. However, the `subprocess` module should take care of that. Use it like so:

```py
import os
import sys
import subprocess

subprocess.call(["python", os.path.join(sys.path[0], __file__)] + sys.argv[1:])
```

Comment: Same error.
    C:\...\python.exe: can't open file 'C:\...\Math': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import os
import sys
os.execv(sys.executable, [sys.executable, '"' + sys.argv[0] + '"'] + sys.argv[1:])
```

Double quotation marks can help windows ignore that space.

It worked for me :)